# display a javascript message before proceeding

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have this code that is to fetch a particular item in the database after the user presses a button. If the item is found I would like to display a confirm message via javascript and I don't know how to show it.

After obtaining the item from the database

```
if(null!=mysqli_fetch_array($res)))
{
    echo ""; // how can I call the javascript code here ?
}
```

and the following confirm box

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function onConfirm()
    {
        return confirm("Display this item ?");        
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: How are you calling the fetch function? You can't break execution of a PHP page via javascript and wait for a confirmation, but you can send multiple AJAX requests for different functions of the page.

Comment: You can't display an alert in the browser while still generating a response on the server. You'll need to have an intermediate page in the browser side where the confirmation takes place.

Comment: Please show me an example of how that can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery and ajax to get the value from the database:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
$.get("ajax.php", function(data){

if(data != "0"){
if(confirm("Display this item ?"))
{

//do something

}
}

});
```

ajax.php:

```
//other db code here

if(null!=mysqli_fetch_array($res)))
{
echo "1"; 
}
else{
echo "0";
}
```

Comment: this should be comment not an answer.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar was adding more info.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of ways you can solve this. A good way is to:

- Send an ajax request to a page
- The page does the mysql stuff and returns<sup>(echo in case of PHP)</sup> the message
- On the callback function use simple way such as `alert()` to show the message.