# On pressing a link to display a javascript alert box

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

[display a javascript message before proceeding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585840/display-a-javascript-message-before-proceeding)
Continuing from that thread, I would like to know if there is any way I can execute a php source code to display some related data from the database once the ajax get function gets the data of '1'

That is

```
$.get("display.php",function(data)
    {
        if(data!='1')
        {
            if(confirm("Display this item"))
            {
                // use this place to execute a php file. But how ?
            }
        }
    }
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't execute a PHP file in JavaScript. At that point you will need to use ajax to get whatever content the PHP script you which to execute produces and then use JavaScript to place it on the page  (or do whatever else it says to do).

Answer (score 3):

You can perform another ajax request (using `$.get` again, in your case)

```
if(confirm("Display this item")) {
    $.get("file.php", function(data) {
        // Handle data
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

call the ajax function again to get data from the php file.